# Out of stack space run time:1004 error

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     Worksheets("Order_Form").Cells(39, 2) = Environ("USERNAME")

    ' Pop up a warning when the user input more than 1000 cases
    If Target.Column = 7 And (Target.Row < 34 And Target.Row > 13) Then
        If Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column) > 1000 Then MsgBox "You are ordering more than 1000 cases", vbCritical
    End If

End Sub
```

This brings up an out of stack space error (runtime error 1004)

It usually happens when i try to edit any cell

Any one have ideas why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line is putting you into an endless loop, as you are initiating a worksheet change inside the Worksheet_Change event. Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     On Error GoTo err_handler
     Application.EnableEvents = False
     Worksheets("Order_Form").Cells(39, 2) = Environ("USERNAME")
     Application.EnableEvents = True

    ' Pop up a warning when the user input more than 1000 cases
    If Target.Column = 7 And (Target.Row < 34 And Target.Row > 13) Then
        If Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column) > 1000 Then MsgBox "You are ordering more than 1000 cases", vbCritical
    End If
err_handler:
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but this has disabled macros on the sheet?

Comment: You should search for Application.EnableEvents and the WorkSheet_Change event. You'll see many similar questions to yours. The short answer is that it doesn't disable macros, it turns off events and keeps you from going into an endless loop of WorkSheet_Changes. If your code stops before it's set back to TRUE, you could have a problem. I'll edit it to be a little safer.

Comment: I have solved it by adding the code to worksheet_open instead, thanks for your help though, very much appreciated! As i just want to set the cell to the username once when it opens

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. I'll point out that your original question was why you got a 1004 error. It seems like I answered that question and gave you a solution based on what you'd shown. If that's so, please consider accepting my answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article. It says its a common problem if one of the cells in your array has more than 911 characters (what a random number). And I see that yours can contain up to 1000. The link contains a work around that should hopefully help you out. Cheers!

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/818808